# R (Rstudio) I forget a ) and my whole script is executed...Is there a way to stop that?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a question about R (personnaly working on it via RStudio). Is there is a magic trick to stop my 2600+ line script to be fully executed whenever I launch a line (ctrl+enter) in which I have forgotten a )

Whenever it happens, I find myself clicking like a maniac on the red "STOP" button on Rstudio but still lose precious minutes.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In RStudio there ought to be a red stop icon in the console window you can click on. Doesn't always work as you note, but usually does.  If worst comes to worst and you're in Windows, you can always stop program in task manager! (But that's a brutal solution.) RStudio will restore your file usually even if you haven't saved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it partially depends on how you're running your script.

If you highlight a selection of code and then do something like ctrl+enter to run those lines then... no. You're kind of stuck doing what you're doing.

If you switch to using ctrl+shift+enter (which is the shortcut for "Source with echo") then you can press the Stop button once and it will cease executing completely.

If you're too used to using something like Ctrl+enter you can modify the keyboard shortcuts to use "Source with echo" instead of just "Run current line or selection"